# Chirik: the long and short of it

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pronunciation

My understanding is that (according to at least some Hebrew grammarians) a *chirik* is classified as a short vowel if it is part of a closed unstressed syllable, and otherwise it is long. A 'short' *chirik* is always written *defective*, whereas a 'long' *chirik* is often, but not exclusively, written *plene*.

This distinction may impact the pronunciation of the syllable containing the *chirik*, and will also effect whether a *sheva* which follows it is *nach* or *na*.

Now, assuming this is correct, what is the status of a *chirik* with a *meteg*? Is this an unstressed 'short' *chirik* or a stressed 'long' chirik? Or is it ambiguous?

The reason I suspect that there may be some ambiguity here is due to examples such as הִשְׁמִֽדְךָ֖ in [Devarim 7:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.7.24?lang=he) where my Tikkun Simanim marks the *sheva* on the *dalet* as *na*, implying that the *chirik* on the *mem* is treated as a long vowel.

Contrast this with תִּֽהְיֶ֖ה in [Devarim 7:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.7.14?lang=he), where, despite the *meteg* on the *tav*, the *chirik* must be a short vowel, as the guttural *heh* cannot take a *sheva na*.

**Bottom-line question: is there an algorithm for determining when a *chirik* is a classified as a long or a short vowel? Are there exceptions?**

Comment: You are assuming that is correct, but you should know there is also a school of thought out there that there is only ever one kind of chirik

Comment: @doubleaa how do they account for the two kinds of רצפה?

Comment: @Heshy meteg, presumably

Comment: Please note that this short-long vowel concept was introduced by [R' Kimchi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Kimhi), and many editions added extra metegs to conform his model. This "sheva na after long vowel" rule most probably wasn't used by Ben Asher either.

Comment: It's not an answer, but it tends to work that after the _chirik_ present in different _binyanim_ (פעל, הפעיל, נפעל, התפעל) the _sheva_ is usually silent (most of them are unstressed closed syllables).

Comment: A meteg always makes the vowel long, irrespective of if it is maleh or haser. Part of the confusion lies in the fact that masoretes typically did not pronounce a Sheva as na after a long vowel.

Comment: @argon So for the masoretes, what was the impact of whether it was long or short? Pronunciation? Something else?

Comment: @Joel the pronunciation would change (and the syllable structure would change to accommodate it). Note that there are some instances of metagim which lengthen a vowel and indicate a vocal sheva, but they are the minority and are somewhat exceptional.